# what is the relation between angularjs, json and API Rest?

Tags: angularjs, rest

what is meaning of annotation @AJAX and @mimetype.json ?
$http in an angularjs controller send an ajax request to a server (java) and the response is json format, so what is the relation of rest API ?

Comment: Do you understand what [**REST**](https://spring.io/understanding/REST) is?

Comment: I know that REST is an architecture but i don't understand exactly what it is it.
I have read a lot but i don't understand yet.